# Procedural generation of wall textures, dividing a pair of triangles (recursively?)

Tags: opengl, recursion

If I make a really simple game that puts the player in a tunnel with square walls made of two triangles (and I have) the walls look a bit boring and even disorienting at certain angles. I'm thinking about taking the data that defines the square panels and procedurally generating a more interesting texture by subdividing each triangle further before randomly perturbing the Z values to get some depth in the wall.

The two triangles look like:

```
typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float Color[4];
    float TexCoord[2];
    float Normal[3];
} Vertex;

const Vertex Vertices[] = {
    // Front
    {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}},
    {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}},
    {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}},
    {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
};
```

This square is transformed into any necessary position to make walls, floor, ceiling.

I can put a texture onto the wall but when looking at the wall from side on (strafing) it is obviously perfectly flat. Modern hardware has triangles to burn so that's why I'm thinking along these lines.

Looks like a job for a recursive algorithm. One problem though, when it comes to the corners the Z values all have to come back to zero or the panels won't tile in 3D and the player will see through the corner gaps where they shouldn't. Simply ruling the edge Z values out of the random process is probably not going to look great - unless maybe all the Z values are changed only by positive values, possibly producing a rough-hewn stone block effect? Knowing which face is forward is obviously important so that seems like one workable solution.

Have you done this kind of procedural generation and if so how did you achieve depth in your walls and how did you handle the panel joins?

Comment: There may be a work-around. Instead of having one texture on each quad, use a bigger texture that stretch for many quads. For example, the r texture coordinate of the first quad could go from 0.0 to 0.1, and the next quad would go from 0.1 o 0.2. That texture would then stretch 10 quads, and the walls would repeat less frequently.

Comment: Also, you can use techniques like mipmapping and anisotropic filtering to make it look nicer in depth and bumpmapping to remove the flatness.